# Как верно расположить 3 элемента textarea

Tags: html, css, css3

Нужно расположить три элемента `<textarea>` таким образом, чтобы: один был слева, другой располагался по центру, а третий - справа. Все одинакового размера и высоты.

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Надо применить CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/Rules/h3ZnB/3/):

```css
.my {
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="my">1</textarea>
<textarea class="my">2</textarea>
<textarea class="my">3</textarea>
```

***UPD:*** А вот [вариант с динамической шириной](http://jsfiddle.net/Rules/h3ZnB/5/)

```css
.my {
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
  width: 32%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="my">1</textarea>
<textarea class="my">2</textarea>
<textarea class="my">3</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

Расположить элементы можно несколькими разными способами:

---

- **`width + margin`**

С размерами в `%` :

```css
body { background: 0% 0% / auto no-repeat url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png'), 0% 0% / auto no-repeat radial-gradient(#fff8, #000f);
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

textarea {
  height: 60%;
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<textarea>1</textarea><textarea>2</textarea><textarea>3</textarea>
```

С размерами в `vh` и `vw` :

```css
body { background: 0% 0% / auto no-repeat url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png'), 0% 0% / auto no-repeat radial-gradient(#fff8, #000f);
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

textarea {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 30vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<textarea>1</textarea><textarea>2</textarea><textarea>3</textarea>
```

---

- **`position`**

```css
body { background: 0% 0% / auto no-repeat url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png'), 0% 0% / auto no-repeat radial-gradient(#fff8, #000f);
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

textarea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 30vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea:first-of-type {
  left: 0;
}
textarea:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 50vw; transform: translateX(-50%);
}
textarea:last-of-type {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<textarea>1</textarea><textarea>2</textarea><textarea>3</textarea>
```

---

- **`float`**

```css
body { background: 0% 0% / auto no-repeat url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png'), 0% 0% / auto no-repeat radial-gradient(#fff8, #000f);
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

textarea {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 30vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea:first-of-type {
  float: right;
}
textarea:last-of-type {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<textarea>1</textarea><textarea>2</textarea><textarea>3</textarea>
```

---

- **`flex`**

```css
body { background: 0% 0% / auto no-repeat url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png'), 0% 0% / auto no-repeat radial-gradient(#fff8, #000f);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

textarea {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 30vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<textarea>1</textarea><textarea>2</textarea><textarea>3</textarea>
```

---

- **`grid`**

```css
body { background: 0% 0% / auto no-repeat url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png'), 0% 0% / auto no-repeat radial-gradient(#fff8, #000f);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 60%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 30%);
  grid-gap: 5%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

textarea {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
```

```html
<textarea>1</textarea><textarea>2</textarea><textarea>3</textarea>
```

*В примерах, в качестве контейнера, используется `<body>`. Это сделано, только для сокращения кода, в рамках ответа. В реальной вёрстке, желательно обернуть все `<textarea>` общим блоком.*

Answer (score 2):

[Используйте свойство `float`](http://jsfiddle.net/UkYrh/):

```css
textarea {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px
}
textarea:first-child {
  margin-left: 0
}
.clear {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ задать одинаковую высоту для всех полей `textarea` это задать им одинаковое количество строк, например: `rows="5"`.

А для равной ширины в 1\3 - width: 33.333%.

Либо использовать для обертки `display: flex` и по умолчанию `align-items: stretch` будет означать что внутренние блоки будут равной высоты (равной высоте наибольшего блока).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

textarea {
  width: 33.333%;
}
```

```html
  
<!--   Вариант: 1 -->
<form>
  <textarea rows="5"></textarea><textarea rows="5"></textarea><textarea rows="5"></textarea>
</form>
  
<!--   Вариант: 2 -->  
<form class="d-flex">
  <textarea rows="10"></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```